# string to xmlNode delphi (or how to add an xml fragment to TXMLDocument)

Tags: delphi, msxml, xmlnode, xmlnodelist, txmldocument

I Have a few text strings that contain well formed XML.

I would like to be able to (1) turn these strings into `IXMLNodes` then (2) append them to an existing `XMLDocument`.  Preferably without declaring a new `XMLDocument` first.

This doesn't seem possible?

Is there any easy way to accomplish something equivalent though? My initial thought was to use the `IXMLNode.XML` (string) property and insert the new strings.  No such luck as `IXMLNode.XML` is Read Only.

Here is an example, if I had the following strings in a `TStringList`,

```
<Property Name="Version" RttiType="tkString"></Property>
<Property Name="ShowSubunit" RttiType="tkBoolean"></Property>
```

And I had the following XML, already loaded into a `TXMLDocument`, how could I easily append the two lines above into the `TXMLDocument` below?

```
<Program Name="PFOO">
  <Class Name="CFOO">
    <Property Name="DBN" RttiType="tkString"/>
    <Property Name="SDate" RttiType="tkClass" ClassType="TXSDATE">12/30/1899</Property>
    <Property Name="XForm" RttiType="tkEnumeration">xfXML</Property>
    <Property Name="Singleton" RttiType="tkBoolean">True</Property>
  </Class>
</Program>
```

Any other (simple) ways to achieve this (no protected hack on the XML property please)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you parse the XML fragments manually and then construct the relevant child nodes/attributes manually, you will have to load the fragments into a temp XMLDocument and then move its nodes to the main XMLDocument as needed.

**Update:** For example:

```
Node := XmlDocument1.DocumentElement.ChildNodes[0]; // <Class> node
Node.ChildNodes.Add(LoadXMLData('<Property Name="Version" RttiType="tkString"></Property>').DocumentElement);
Node.ChildNodes.Add(LoadXMLData('<Property Name="ShowSubunit" RttiType="tkBoolean"></Property>').DocumentElement);
```

Comment: This may indeed be the only way to go.  Might you be able to provide me with a simple example?

Comment: Just an fyi, I did try myself, but get 'Property or Method "importNode" is not supported by DOM Vendor "MSXML"'

Comment: Here is the code I tried:          currProgNode.DOMNode.ownerDocument.importNode(lclXMLObj.Node.DOMNode,true);  (where lclXMLObj is of type TXMLDocument and currProgNode is of type IXMLNode, basically trying to copy nodes across XML Docs as suggested).  I really feel that this should be much easier.  I hope I am missing something obvious.  Thank you again.

Comment: You don't need to drop down to the DOM level to move nodes between documents. Simply `Add()` or `Insert()` an `IXMLNode` into the `ChildNodes` of another `IXMLNode` and it will automatic move to the new document if needed. I updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Thank you for the redirection (and the answer!).  I wasted much time at the DOM level.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [SimpleStorage](http://www.cromis.net/blog/downloads/simplestorage/). For now its tied to OmniXML, but its powerfull. What you want would look like this:

```
CurrentNode.Append(StorageFromXML('<Node>Content</Node>'));
```

One line of code.

Comment: Thank you.  It's a wonderfully simple approach, unfortunately, I am limited to TXMLDocument or MSXML directly.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: I see you found the solution. It is unfortunately the only viable way in your case. Vanila XML is so clumsy to work with, that is why I made SimpleStorage. When I will have some time I plan to expand it and make it compatible with just about any structured storage out there :)